# WebDeploy from TFS using Build Definitions to IIS site containing files changed by users

Tags: asp.net, tfs, msbuild, webdeploy, iis-8.5

I use Build Definitions and WebDeploy in order to simplify pushing updates from a Team Foundation Server to an ASP.NET Web Application on my IIS server.

But files such as, .cshtml, .js, .css, etc. may get changed by the users of the web application via an interface on the web site.

My issue is, when deploying my web application via Build Definitions, all files will get overwritten. I want to avoid overwriting the files that the users have changed.

As I it, I have the following solutions

1. Manually copy all files (.cshtml, js, css, .etc) and merge them into my source code
2. On every build, make a backup, and restore the files that the users have changed and do manual merges on changed files
3. Somehow pull the files from the IIS to the TFS and merge them

Is options #3 possible, I'm looking for as much automation as possible.

Comment: How did you deploy before you used Web Deploy? Even using copy and paste would have overwritten changed files.

Comment: We used BeyondCompare which has built-in FTP functionality. But that meant we had to build it locally and then upload.

Comment: So you just manually took into account the changes that the users had made.

Comment: Yes. I do not recommend this, as it is very error prone and often results in errors. This is also the reason I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would look to seperate out the bits that the customer customizes from the core functionality of my product. They should never customize the files that i deploy and instead add files that override yours.

I assume that you want to be able to upgrade them continuously.

Comment: Agree. One should use includes to pull in customer variations. It can be easily done in classic ASP, in ASP.MVC views, in CSS, in HTML.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately this is not possible. I'm looking for a solution where i can either be promped that there are changes, the changed files will not get overwritten, or the crazy-insanely-bad solution where i somehow connect the TFS to the IIS server.

Comment: You are going to have to write that yourself. Use a PowerShell script for the deployment and figure out what is me from there.